# Sinatra haml Select and Delete several files

Tags: ruby, checkbox, sinatra, haml, parameters

I'm trying to delete several files based on a list but I'm having problems getting the params from the chekcbox's

This is my list.haml:

```
%form(method="post" action="/selection" enctype="multipart/form-data")
        -   @files.each do |file|
            %br
            %input{:type => "checkbox", :name => "checkbox[]", :value => "#{file}" }
            =file
        %br
        %input(type='submit' value="Delete Selected Files")
```

Now, for now I was just trying to see what I get in params, so I can later deal with how to delete this list of files.

```
params.inspect
```

"Gives me" ≃> {"checkbox"=>["yet_another_file.txt", "file1", "file2"]}

But I can't figure out how do I put this into an Array so I can do something like

```
var.each do |c|
    puts c
end
```

I tried var = params[:checkbox] but var is empty, does anyone now how can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `var = params["checkbox"]`, since the params key is not a symbol, but a string.

Comment: Makes sense, but I still get "nil" and I really can't figure out why...

If params.inpect shows my the hash with values, how is this possible, could it be a bug?

Comment: I write a sinatra app to test this, but seems alright. Please show us your post route for `/selection`.

Comment: You're right... (I killed shotgun proccess) and just tested with a simple route:

post '/selection' do    
  var = params['checkbox']
  "#{var}" 
end

Thanks for the help